# Restoring MySQL 8.0 server from cold backup files

Tags: mysql, restore, mysql-8.0

Recently, my database server running MySQL 8.0 crashed due to power outage. I have access to a cold backup (i.e., all physical files) of the server before the crash occurred. I do not have any other backups (e.g., mysqldump) of the server.

Now, I am trying to restore the server from the backup files that I have. The manual for this procedure suggests that I can directly copy all .ibd files as long as I can set up identical table structures (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-migration.html).

Meanwhile, I am unable to find a way to create tables that are identical to those in the crashed system (I vaguely remember that when I did this years ago, I can restore table schema using .frm files but they do not seem to exist anymore in MySQL 8.0).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're reading the wrong page. Restoring from a file system ("raw") backup doesn't require you to "set up identical table structures"; simply copy *all* MySQL files from the backup to their original location, then start MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to copy everything in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data and paste in the new location but that does not appear to work.